# How to compile Asus-syntec-webcam-driver stk11xx

Tags: 11.04, laptop, webcam, compiling

i have asus v1s and some time ago i was able to easily compile and install it. but now compiling fails... i hope u guys know what i can do, if there is anything that can be done...

after

```
svn checkout https://syntekdriver.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/syntekdriver syntekdriver
```

and

```
cd ./syntekdriver/trunk/driver
```

as well as

```
make -f Makefile.standalone
```

i got:

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.36.2/build SUBDIRS=/home/berot3/syntekdriver/trunk/driver modules
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/berot3/syntekdriver/trunk/driver/stk11xx-usb.o
  CC [M]  /home/berot3/syntekdriver/trunk/driver/stk11xx-v4l.o
/home/berot3/syntekdriver/trunk/driver/stk11xx-v4l.c:43:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: File not found!
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/berot3/syntekdriver/trunk/driver/stk11xx-v4l.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/berot3/syntekdriver/trunk/driver] Error 2
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic'
make: *** [driver] Error 2
```

same for

- http://bookeldor-net.info/merdier/Makefile-syntekdriver
- http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OM0zVNlYiVQJ:bookeldor-net.info/merdier/Makefile-syntekdriver+http://bookeldor-net.info/merdier/Makefile-syntekdriver&hl=de&strip=1

Comment: Is `linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic` installed?

Answer (score 1):

Add the user to video group.

Then, in accordance with http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/syntek download syntek.tar.gz http://ubuntuone.com/p/pQc/, and next:

Unpack

```
tar xvf ~/syntek.tar.gz
```

Go to the drivers directory in the terminal

```
cd ~/syntek/driver
make -f Makefile-syntekdriver
make -f Makefile-syntekdriver install
sudo modprobe stk11xx
dmesg |tail
```

For example, my log

```
[ 1129.566489] stk11xx: Copyright(c) 2006-2009 Nicolas VIVIEN
[ 1129.566512] stk11xx: Syntek USB2.0 - STK-1135 based webcam found.
[ 1129.566514] stk11xx: Syntek AVStream USB2.0 1.3M WebCam - Product ID 0x6A51.
[ 1129.566516] stk11xx: Release: 0005
[ 1129.566518] stk11xx: Number of interfaces : 1
[ 1129.568024] stk11xx: Initialize USB2.0 Syntek Camera
[ 1130.559109] stk11xx: Syntek USB2.0 Camera is ready
[ 1130.559243] stk11xx: Syntek USB2.0 Camera is now controlling video device /dev/video0
[ 1130.559291] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb_stk11xx_driver
[ 1130.559296] stk11xx: v2.2.0 : Syntek USB Video Camera
```

Option vertical and horizontal flip for all users:

Add to /etc/rc.local, before the line exit 0, the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

vertical flip

```
echo '1' > /sys/class/video4linux/video0/vflip
```

horizontal flip

```
echo '1' > /sys/class/video4linux/video0/hflip
```

Reload the kernel module

And that's all. Works on Ubuntu 11.04.

I'm glad if I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Very same problem...
It seems they have the solution here :
https://sourceforge.net/projects/syntekdriver/forums/forum/616182/topic/4427484
but I can't figure how to apply the changes they talk about.

If anyone knows how to ... ?

Julien

edit : the changes work, see http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/syntek (updated) for explanations !

Answer (score 0):

Works well, older version of skype-ubuntu-intrepid_2.1.0.81-1_amd64.deb. There is no trouble with the camera :-)